# How to map table rows as potential rows of different interfaces in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have the following interfaces,

```
export interface IUserRow {
    id: string,
    state: string,
    email: string,
}

export interface ITableRow {
    id: string,
    [key: string]: any;
}

export type Rows = ITableRow | IUserRow; // different row types, such as IPostRow to be added later
```

And I'm mapping a table,

```
const instanceOfUser = (object: any): object is IUserRow => 'member' in object;

const determineOnRowClick = (row: Rows, onRowClick: any) => {
  if (instanceOfUser(row)) {
    // never entered, always returns false
    const rowId = row.id;
    const view = row.state === 'Active' ? 'edit' : 'add';

    return onRowClick(rowId, view);
  }

  return onRowClick(row.id);
}
. . .
<TableBody className={tableClasses.tbody}>
  {rows.map((row: Rows, i: number) => (
    <TableRow
      onClick={() => determineOnRowClick(row, onRowClick ?? null)}
      key={row.id || i}
    >
. . .
```

I am trying to dynamically determine the `onRowClick` method, and the line,

```
if (instanceOfUser(row)) {
. . .
```

is never entered. Is this possible with typescript, to declare the current element in the map method as an element that could be a member of more than one interface? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const determineOnRowClick = (row: Rows, onRowClick: any) => {
  if ((row as IUserRow).email) {
    const rowId = row.id;
    const view = row.state === 'Active' ? 'edit' : 'add';
    return onRowClick(rowId, view);
  }

  return onRowClick(row.id);
}
```

If `row` has no `email` set, this will evaluate to `false`. You need to check this using `...as IUserRow` to let typescript know, that there may be an attribute `email`.

Comment: This works! Question, however -- what's the point of `if ((row as IUserRow).email)` if I can just do `if (row.email) `?

Comment: @MikeK during development ts will give you an error like `property 'email' does not exist on type 'ITableRow` or smth. similar since row has either a type of `IUserRow` or `ITableRow` and `email` does only exist in `IUserRow`